# Update FileMaker Table over odbc

Tags: php, mysql, filemaker

i am trying to update a Table on FileMaker but am getting this error:
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0001/(1:90): There is an error in the syntax of the query., SQL state 42000 in SQLExecDirect in C:...

here is my code:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("DSN=Server;Database=FM_File;UID=odbc;PWD=1234", "odbc", "1234");
$result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT ID_FM, Street FROM Table WHERE Street LIKE '%AVENUE%'");

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ID_FM = $row["ID_FM"];
    $Street = $row["Street"];

    $Street_neu = str_replace("AVENUE", "AV", $Street);

    $update = "UPDATE Table SET Street='$Street_neu' WHERE ID_FM=" . $ID_FM;    
    $data_update = odbc_exec($conn, $update);       
}    
odbc_close($conn);
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As your error states you have incorrect syntax. I do not like $ in the string value, but this is probably OK. You can't use a table called Table in SQL statement - it is the reserved word. I would recommend changing the name. If you can't, try to escape it:

```
"SELECT ID_FM, Street FROM \"Table\" WHERE Street LIKE '%AVENUE%'"
```

and

```
"UPDATE \"Table\" SET Street='$Street_neu' WHERE ID_FM=" . $ID_FM;
```

FileMaker also uses its own notation for reserved words - ${reserveword}. I don't think it applies to its version of SQL, but you can try if the other one fails

Comment: thank you for your answer Nikolai Kant. But the Table Name was just an example. In the meantime a have the solution. I have forgotten to use `addslashes`, because of the special characters. thank you

Comment: I see. I would suggest using myTable or sampleTable in your examples to avoid confusion.